# In Android Studio/XML, is there anything similar to ERB?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm coming from the (wonderful) Ruby on Rails world: so I'm used to being able to programmatically embed ruby in YAML files. Is there anything similar in the Android/java/XML world? (see below). Can I do anything like this?

`<xml>
  <date><%= date %></date>
  <time><%= Time.now %></time>
  <dbaccess>
    <hostname><%= hostname %></hostname>
    <username><%= username %></username>
  </dbaccess>
  <myfiles><%= myfiles %></myfiles>
</xml>`

Comment: where exactly you are planing to do this?

Answer (score 2):

As an old Ruby on Rails developer myself, the short answer is No.

In Ruby on Rails we can include Ruby code in our Views.

In Android we can't include Java code in our Views (XML defined in Res folder).

============================

In Ruby on Rails, first Controller is run and then it passes results to Views. So in views we can still use Ruby code to change results before showing.

In Android it is the other way around. We load a layout (XML defined layout in Res/layout folder) in Java and there we can change layout using java code if we like.
If hope it helps to understand.

Comment: thanks, I was thinking it was probably so, but hoping it wasn't. The other useful place is in the res/values XML definitions of constants. I use ERB frequently in setting up variances within constants (such as a date, time), among other things.

Comment: You can override values in your java code like in your Activity class but you can't set values in xml using java code.